# No apps can perform this action Android Intent using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I am using the following code snippets from Android official documentation to share content through applications using `Intent` but it says "No apps can perform this action." on a physical device. I have messengers, email client and text message clients installed.

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share")
}

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sharing"))
```

Comment: "in Kotlin" did it work in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I know:

As [Fredy Mederos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6386664/fredy-mederos) said, the value that you are modified is the `Activity.getIntent`, not the `new Intent`.

You should write like this:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        type = "text/plain"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share")
    }
```

or more precise:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
        this.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        this.type = "text/plain"
        this.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share")
    }
```

the `this` is pointed to your initialized `new Intent()`.

Comment: Accepted this answer for pointing out the `this` keyword which refers to initialized intent.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change your intent initialization with apply to this:

```
val intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    type = "text/plain"
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share")
}
```

When you modify the intent variable inside the apply you are modifying the activity intent not the brand new intent.

copy this code and you will see what i'm talking about:

```
val intent_1 = Intent().apply {
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    intent.type = "text/plain"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share")
}
```

Comment: I tried this before but it didn’t work. The reason could be setting content on the activity intent in apply block not the on newly created

Answer (score 0):

The following code works instead of above posted in the question.

```
val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
i.type = "text/plain"
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Content to share")
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sharing"))
```

I am not sure why the code in the question does not work but my guess is that `intent` is related to the activity's intent and it works when I instantiated another object from `Intent` class.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Sharing"))`
by  `startActivity(i)`

Comment: Can you explain why that should be neccessary?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending
before use createChooser  please Verify the intent will resolve to at least one activity  

if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(chooser)
}